# Using a randomization to compare frequencies in two groups?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution, frequency, randomized-tests

I have a dataset of males and females and whether they dispersed (yes = 1). For example:

```
Male   0
Male   0
Male   0
Male   0
Male   0
Female 0
Female 1
Female 0
```

I'm interested in performing a randomization to determine if the frequency of dispersal is different between males and females. However, very few individuals dispersed, so I do not meet the assumptions of a chi-square test. Of 42 males, 0 dispersed. Of 27 females, 4 dispersed.

I understand that I can do a randomization with data for means, but am less clear if I can do this with binomial data?

Also, is there a simple way to do this in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can do a randomization test analgous to chi-square test of association.  Have you considered the `simulate.p.values` option in `chisq.test` in R?  But with 0 positive observations in one group and 4 observations on the other group, you have to consider what could be concluded from the results.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the binomial test as the assumptions are less restrictive than the chi-squared test. Search on binom.test function in R.

Comment: I don't think the binomial test would solve the problem, as the question asks about what is essentially a 2 x 2 contingency table.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to compare two proportions. R's prop.test function does that.

Edited after discussion: Apparently this uses an asymptotic approximation that gives a warning for these data, probably because of too small success numbers.

Thinking about this more, Fisher's exact test should do what you want. This is a permutation test for whether two binary variables (male/female and 0/1) are unrelated.

```
> x <- c(0,4,42,23)
> x<-as.matrix(x)
> dim(x) <- c(2,2)

> fisher.test(x)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  x
p-value = 0.0203
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.0000000 0.9167391
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
         0
```

Comment: Is this test appropriate with the small counts in the data?

Comment: The test doesn't assume that counts are large, so it should be fine. I don't think there's any better for this situation.

Comment: The function will give a warning in the case of these data, that the chi-square result may not be accurate. It gives this warning if any n*x/n is < 5. In this case, with one x being 0, obviously it triggers this warning.

Comment: Ah, you're right. This wasn't transparent from the help page.

Comment: [Comments above refer to the `prop.test` function, not the `fisher.test` function.]

Comment: @Sal.Mangiafico: Actually the fisher.test should be pretty similar to chisq.test with simulate.p.value=TRUE as proposed by you in your first comment. In this case fisher.test doesn't use Monte Carlo approximation and seems preferable to me (test statistic and null hypothesis are not quite identical), however I'd be curious if you have something to say on the comparison between the two (in this case results are pretty much identical).

Comment: I don't have have much intelligent to say about the difference between the two.  I suppose the practical limit to using `fisher.test` is the computing power for tables with high counts or large tables.  But `fisher.test` also has a `simulate.p.values` option.  Note that there is also a `chisq_test` function in the `coin` package`.

Comment: simulate.p.values in fisher.test is only relevant for larger than 2*2 tables. For 2*2 tables it will compute precise p-values.